# how select second item az default in dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a dropdownlist, in mvc 3 razor:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
       "SelectedLicensesID",
            new SelectList(Model, "LicensesID", "LicenseUI"))
```

It contains 5 items.  How can i set second item as the default item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, what's it's `LicensesID` value. If you know it you could:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedLicensesID",
    new SelectList(Model, "LicensesID", "LicenseUI", "123")
)
```

where 123 is the `LicensesID` of the item you want preselected.

Another possibility is to do this in the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = ...
    // preselect the item that has LicensesID=123
    ViewData["SelectedLicensesID"] = "123";
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: i do not know value of LicensesID ,LicensesID is a identity column in table in database

Comment: @motevallizadeh, of course that you know the value, it's the `LicensesID` property of the second element in the list you fetched from the database and used as model.